# How to get values from class to trigger

Tags: apex

I'm having a class with a picklistfield (field1) and in that I'm getting values as

```
string field1;
Public string getfield1(){return field1;}
public void setTemplate(string field1){this.field1 = field1;}
       public list<selectoption> gettempname()
      {
          list<selectoption> option = new list<selectoption>();   

          for(object__c design : [select name from object__c limit 10] )         
             option.add(new selectoption(design.name,design.name));
             return option;     
     }
```

and using this in a query as

```
object1__c emailcontentinfo = [select field12__c from object1__c  where object__r.name =:field1 limit 1 ];
```

now I'm writing a trigger on another object(object3).In this need to get the values of field1....How can I get it...H

Comment: What is the relationship between the objects?

Comment: Call the method of the class to get the same values in the trigger

Comment: object1__c is a lookup for object__c.and object3 don't have any relation with this two objects.Is it possible to get the field1?

Comment: declare the variable field1 as static and do classname.field1 in your trigger

Comment: What about bulkification? Can you be sure only one of these will come through at a time? If not you will have to add all values to a list and query for Object3 having those values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make this a static property, it will be available for the duration of the transaction, thus you can refer to it in your trigger.  E.g. assuming your class is MyClass:

```
public static string field1;
Public string getfield1(){return MyClass.field1;}
public void setTemplate(string field1){MyClass.field1 = field1;}
```

Then in the trigger you can have:

```
object1__c emailcontentinfo = [select field12__c from object1__c  where object__r.name =:MyClass.field1 limit 1 ];
```

Comment: better explained than my one liner :)